# SSE Intrinsics - Logical NOT Optimization

Tags: c++, performance, openmp, sse, simd

I am performing bitwise NOT operations on pixels in an image using SSE.

I have some questions:

1. Can this be optimized further using OpenMP?
2. Are there any bottlenecks in my algorithm that could be optimized?

Here is my code:

```
unsigned int iSSE2Size = (SrcImage1.GetHeight() * (SrcImage1.GetStepBytes() >> 1)) >> 3;
__m128i *m_ucSrcPtr = (__m128i *)SrcImage1.GetWordPtr();
__m128i *m_ucDstPtr = (__m128i *)DestImage.GetWordPtr();
__m128i iMaxVal = _mm_set1_epi16(0xFFFF); 
unsigned short *srcRowPtr, *dstRowPtr;
while (iSSE2Size-- > 0)
{
    *m_ucDstPtr = _mm_andnot_si128(*m_ucSrcPtr, iMaxVal );
    m_ucSrcPtr++;
    m_ucDstPtr++;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried loop unrolling?

Comment: Can you wrap this in a function that actually compiles, so we can look at the compiler output?

Comment: Why don't you just use `_mm_set1_epi16(65535)`, and let the compiler worry about how to get the data there.  (hint, it will do a better job than storing to a local array on the stack and then loading from there.  A register of all-ones can be generated on the fly with `pcmpeqw same,same`, and CPUs recognize that idiom as being independent of the old value, like for xor-zeroing.  Let the compiler do this for you, though.)

Comment: Do you get decent results from auto-vectorizing?  I'd guess that `a[i] = ~a[i]` would auto-vectorize nicely.  Writing it as an XOR with all-ones (i.e. `~0ULL`) might also help, esp. if you're targeting AVX.  (`VPANDN` inverts the register operand, not the register/memory operand).  Are you targetting AVX, or is this the SSE2-only version?  AVX could use 256b FP boolean operations, which is ok since you can only sustain one vector per clock throughput anyway, since you're storing the results back to memory.   What microarchitecture(s) are you tuning for, and which are you benchmarking on?

Comment: Are you bottlenecked on memory bandwidth, or is the image already hot in L1 or L2 cache?  How big are your images?  If you were going to multithread this, though, it would make more sense for each thread to work on a separate image, unless each image is really gigantic.  (OpenMP is one way to do threading, as well as SIMD).  Also, what compiler are you using?

Comment: Why are you changing the rounding mode?  Your code doesn't do any FP operations, unless `SrcImage1.SembufGetHeight()` returns a `float` or `double`.

Comment: 79 ms seems very high, unless either your images are huge, or you forgot to turn on compiler optimisation, or you are using a 20 year old computer?

Comment: For a small number of iterations the OpenMP overhead will bee too large and for large sizes the operations is memory bandwidth bound. That does not necessarily mean you will see no benefit for large sizes using threads but it certainly won't scale with the number of threads on a single socket system.   You may see some befit if the size fits between L2 and L3.

Comment: @PaulR: My 17 year old Pentium III 450MHz router / mail server doesn't support SSE2, only SSE1 :P

Comment: @PeterCordes: `xorps` and `andnps` are in SSE.

Comment: @EOF: Yes, the basic algo is implementable in SSE1, but the OP's code as posted uses SSE2, so we can rule out PIII / Athlon-XP or older.

Comment: @Kenim: you edited out the timing numbers a while ago, and simplified the code a lot.  Did that affect the performance noticeably?  If so, then post it as an answer and revert the question.  If not, then edit the question to address the comments, esp: What compiler are you using?  What  microarchitectures do you care about performance on?  Do you already have an AVX/AVX2 version for new CPUs?  Do you have multiple images to potentially process in parallel?  What image size / cache hotness are you dealing with?  You can also reply in comments, but all important info should be in the question.

Comment: It looks like the OP is either unaware of comments or doesn't know how to respond to them - he hasn't replied to any of the above questions/suggestions so far. Maybe he's on a mobile device or some such and can't see the comments ? @KenimKM: are you there ?

Comment: @Paul. took a couple of days off from work. i am sorry. i am using Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 C++ Compiler. i have tried openmp tiling approach to optimize my code. here is how i am doing it

__m128i* SrcPtr_array[8] = { SrcPtr, SrcPtr + iTileHt, SrcPtr + 2 * iTileHt, SrcPtr + 3 * iTileHt, SrcPtr + 4 * iTileHt, SrcPtr + 5 * iTileHt, SrcPtr + 6 * iTileHt, SrcPtr + 7 * iTileHt };
__m128i* DstPtr_array[8] = { DstPtr, DstPtr + iTileHt, DstPtr + 2 * iTileHt, DstPtr + 3 * iTileHt, DstPtr + 4 * iTileHt, DstPtr + 5 * iTileHt, DstPtr + 6 * iTileHt, DstPtr + 7 * iTileHt };

Comment: Hi @KenimKM: you might want to [edit] your question to include any new information or code such as the attempt at tiling in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes you could try to both loop unroll and use OpenMP to optimize your code.

   ```
   #pragma omp parallel for
   for (;iSSE2Size-=2 > 0;)
   {
       *m_ucDstPtr = _mm_andnot_si128(*m_ucSrcPtr, iMaxVal );
       m_ucSrcPtr++;
       m_ucDstPtr++;

       *m_ucDstPtr = _mm_andnot_si128(*m_ucSrcPtr, iMaxVal );
       m_ucSrcPtr++;
       m_ucDstPtr++;
   }
   ```

   Note that you can probably unroll more than once to enhance performance.
2. I don't see any bottlenecks in the snippet you provided.